# How to generate a new print job for each page - FastReports

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I'm using FastReports to generate tags. I have 1600 different tags (pages) to print but if it happens any problem during the printing , I lose all my progress.

So I want to know if there is any way to generate a different print job for each page (tag), so 1600 different print jobs are submitted.

Comment: Can You rephrase your question. Show what's done.. maybe some code example. It's quite hard for others probably to understand what exactly You need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want a different print job for every page (tags), isn't that ?.

I would remove the MasterData of your report, so the report doesn't loop automatically through every record of your dataset, just showing the active record. And then code a loop for the dataset, preparing and sending the report to the printer on each row (tag), so it would send a different print job with a single page every time.

Basically you just put your current code within a loop so it's executed once per every record, and remove the masterdata so it only shows the current record.

Comment: Yes, thats what I want, a different print job for every page. I'll try like you suggested.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I personally prefer to loop a ClientDataset with a WHILE (while not ClientDataSet1.Eof) instead of your FOR construction, but both should work fine. :-)

Comment: I removed the MasterData1 from the report and added this code:   `ClientDataSet1.First;
  for I := 0 to ClientDataSet1.Recordcount -1 do
  begin
    frxReport.PrepareReport();
    frxReport.Print;
    ClientDataSet1.next;
  end;`